# Get head of current template from component

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development

Is it possible to retrieve the `<head>` of a document from a component then use it within a `raw` view?

I'm know if you use `format=raw` you can have the document only output what the component returns (i.e. without any other modules, template stuff, etc.)

I'm trying to create a view for my component that includes a bit of the template (specifically the `<head>`) and then only what my component generates (I plan on passing this to a a CLI utility `wkhtmltopdf` to generate a PDF of the output).

I need the `head` as my component relies on template CSS for styling, but I don't want anything else - basically:

```
<html>
<head>
...css, js, title, etc from template...
</head>
<body>
...ONLY output from my component, like 'format=raw'...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, you can't. Try [`domPDF`](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/downloads/list) and visit [this tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_PDF_views).

Comment: This looks good, but it would mean my component is dependent on the J! install having `dompdf` installed, `/html/renderer` copied to `/pdf/renderer` amongst other non-standard dependencies. Unless I write an installation script to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to perform it as you expect:

The `view.raw.php` would be something like this:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

class YOURCOMPONENTViewYOURVIEW extends JViewLegacy // or JView depends on J! version
{
    public function display($tpl = 'raw')
    {
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

The `default_raw.php` file inside `tmpl` folder would be something like this:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;
$url = jUri::base();

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($contents);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$head = $xpath->query('/html/head')->item(0);
$head = $dom->saveHTML($head);
echo '<html>' . $head . '<body>BLAH BLAH</body></html>'
```

Comment: This is almost perfect - just need to change ->saveXml at the end to saveHtml.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, there is no `<head>` in JDocumentRaw.
The raw format is meant to generate non-HTML output, without loading the template at all.

If you want to only generate the component output as a HTML page using the template design, then you should add  `&tmpl=component` to the URL.
This will load the `component.php` file in your template instead of the `index.php`. It should not load any module position and only output the component.
This is especially useful for modal windows and the like.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks. Just looked at the `component.php` that ships with the template we use and it is missing some of the key statements, but I think I can get this to work and it keeps things as uncoupled as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way I can capture the full output of this (i.e. `component.php` including my component output) from within the controller method, and do something with it? I'm playing with `JDocument` but no such luck yet...

Comment: I doubt you can do this in your component. Simply because of the order in which the stuff is loaded.
You would have to do that in a system plugin in an event after the rendering is done.

Comment: Yeah, I'm coming across that. I can load `component.php` via   `$document->render(false, array("template" => "templateName", "file" => "component.php"));`, but it obviously doesn't contain the component output yet. I could pass a URL to my PDF generator, but that won't have the session data I need, and there doesn't seem to be a way to load up an existing session

Comment: The only thing I can think of doing is taking that `render`ed output, parsing the HTML returned, and injecting my output into the body, but that is pretty hacky.